# How to read application properties such as created, modified of PE file with hex editor?

Tags: x86, exe, portable-executable

I am studying PE file format, so I am going to make a simple PE parser in assembly.
I could understand PE headers, but I can't read application properties such as **created, modified, MD5, SHA-1** and so on.
How can I find these informations manually in PE file with hex editor?
Thank you.

Comment: If you're talking about the creation time and modification time of the file, those are filesystem metadata, not part of the file data itself. That's why all files can have that, even `.txt` and `.asm`, even empty files.  The MD5 and SHA-1 are also probably just computed from the file data, unless PE files have place to put hashes for some section or something that doesn't include the location where the hash is stored.

Comment: More comfortable tool for inspection of PE than hex viewer is [PEview.exe](http://wjradburn.com/software/) by Wayne J. Radburn. There are no hashes in PE headers, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are six places in a PE file where you can find a timestamp:

1. [**In the COFF header**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#coff-file-header-object-and-image). The timestamp is the time when the PE was created.
2. [**In the delay-load import address table**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#the-delay-load-directory-table). The timestamp is the same as point 4.
3. [**In the export directory table**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#export-directory-table). The timestamp is the time when the exported data was created.
4. [**In the import directory table**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#import-directory-table). The timestamp of the imported data (see point 3).
5. [**In the load configuration directory**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#load-configuration-layout). The timestamp is the time when the configuration data was created.
6. [**In the resource directory**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#resource-directory-table). The timestamp is the time when the resource was compiled.

All these timestamps are 32-bit fields counting the seconds since the UNIX Epoch. The values 0 and 0xffffffff mark an invalid timestamp.
These fields have little relevance for the loader so they don't have to be truthful at all.
You can find the offset of these fields with some basic math, the linked page lists each field along with its offset from the parent header.

The "modified" and "created" times are attributes of the file where the PE is stored.
These attributes are not used by the loader and are not generally preserved as the file is transferred from one machine to another (e.g. through an HTTP download).
These attributes are read with specific system calls <sup>[[1](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat)] [[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileinformationbyhandle)]</sup>.

The MD5 and SHA1 hashes are not fields of the PE file format, they are computed at runtime by your PE viewer of choice.
You can find many C implementations<sup>[[1](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/libkern/crypto/sha1.c.auto.html)]</sup> of these hashes that follow the *XInit*/*XUpdate*/*XFinal* pattern.
Once you have a working C implementation you can either translate that to assembly or link against it.
To compute the hash of a PE all you have to do is initialize a hash context, update it with the whole PE data as read from the file, and finalize the context into a digest (that you can display as a hex string).